# ¿Se puede definir el orden de creación de las columnas en una table al utilizar Hibernate con Panache en Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Tengo la siguiente entidad:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente extends PanacheEntity{

    @Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "apellido_paterno", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String apellidoPaterno;

    @Column(name = "apellido_materno", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String apellidoMaterno;

    @Column(name = "numero_documento", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String numeroDocumento;

    @Column(name = "fecha_nacimiento", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate fechaNacimiento;
}
```

Al crearse la tabla en la base de datos mediante Hibernate ordena las columnas por orden alfabético:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo deseo que las columnas se creen en el orden que fueron declaradas, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿hay alguna manera de hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

no solucione eso pero para darte una solucion
seria que antes este creado tu base de datos con tus tablas de acuerdo al orden que especificas, despues en la propiedad de tu aplicativo  checas esto:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/402137)